# File/Variable Error Java

Tags: java, file, variables, expression

This code looks through hundreds of names and finds the popularity and meaning of them. I have two questions. what I am trying to accomplish where the error is, is to print text of the meaning of the name on to the top of my graph.
1. How can I fix this error:

```
BabyNames.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
      String meanings = findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);
```

2. By the time findingStatistics runs through twice, variable statistics is only holding the information for the meaning of the name. How can I access the popularity of the name to use my graph? Right now I have the whole method equal to the statistics, which is just the meaning.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BabyNames{ //ADD COMMENTS
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 
   private static String nameFinal;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780,560);
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      Scanner nameFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      Scanner meaningsFile = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      Scanner nameFile2 = new Scanner(new File("names2.txt"));
      intro();
      fixedGraph(g);
      nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);
      if(STARTINGYEAR == 1890){
         findingStatistics(console,nameFile);;
         changingGraph(console,g);
      }
      else{
         findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);
         changingGraph(console,g);
      }
      findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);
   }



   public static void intro(){
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");
      System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
      System.out.println("since 1890" );
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Name: ");
   }

   public static String nameToLowerCase(Scanner console){   
      String originalName = console.next();
      String name = "" ;
      int lengthOfName = originalName.length();
      String beginingOfName = originalName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String endOfName = originalName.substring(1,lengthOfName).toLowerCase();
      name = beginingOfName + endOfName;
      return name;
   }
   public static String findingStatistics(Scanner console, Scanner data){
     // String nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);
      boolean goesThroughOnce = false; //
      String statistics = "";
      String currWord = "";
      String currLine = "";
      while (data.hasNext() && goesThroughOnce == false){ 
         currLine = data.nextLine();
         Scanner lineBeingRead = new Scanner(currLine); //make other scanners?? for each file
         currWord = lineBeingRead.next(); //

         if (currWord.equals(nameFinal) || currWord.equals(nameFinal.toUpperCase())){   //         
            statistics = currLine;
            goesThroughOnce = true;
            System.out.println(statistics);
         }
         else{
         }
      }
      return statistics;
   }
   public static void fixedGraph(Graphics g){ //Draws fixed things such as gray blocks and black lines
      g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      g.fillRect(0,0,780,HEIGHT);
      g.fillRect(0,560-HEIGHT,780,HEIGHT);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawLine(0,HEIGHT,780,HEIGHT);
      g.drawLine(0,560-HEIGHT,780,560-HEIGHT);
   }

   public static void changingGraph(Scanner console, Graphics g){  
      String meanings = findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);
      g.drawString("" + meanings,0,16); //draws meaning text
      int startingYear = STARTINGYEAR;
      int amountOfDecades = 0;
      if(startingYear == 1890){
         amountOfDecades = 13;
      }
      else{
         amountOfDecades = 8;
      }
      g.drawString("" + startingYear,0,552); //fencepost 
      for(int i=0; i<=amountOfDecades;i++){ 
         int year = startingYear + (10 * i);
         g.drawString("" + year,(WIDTH*i),552); //draws decade numbers
      }      
   }
}
```

If I add a // on what the error was and not include that, just so one can understand the code better, for the name "Aaron" it should print out:

```
Name: AARON
Aaron f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 883 0 0 0
AARON m English, Biblical From the Hebrew name ??????? ('Aharon) which is most likely of unknown Egyptian origin.
```

Shortly, I'm trying to make it print text on the graph, and making two variables for the meaning and popularity (I have them both under statistics).

Answer (score 1):

Your `changingGraph` method is only using `console` in order to work out `meanings`, for which of course, it also needs `meaningsFile`.  It would make far more sense to remove the call to `findingStatistics` from `changingGraph`, especially since you are calling it from `main` anyway.

So change the signature of `changingGraph` so that it takes `meanings` as a parameter, as well as removing the first line of the method body.  It will then look like this.

```
public static void changingGraph(String meanings, Graphics g){  
    g.drawString("" + meanings,0,16); //draws meaning text
    // ... and so on.
```

Then, when you call it, pass the value that was returned from the previous call to `findingStatistics`.  So in your `main` method, you'll have this.

```
  if(STARTINGYEAR == 1890){
     findingStatistics(console,nameFile);
  }
  else{
     findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);
  }
  String meanings = findingStatistics(console, meaningsFile);
  changingGraph(meanings, g);
```

Comment: I think you meant "meanings" to be "popularity" ? Because the nameFiles have the popularity information in it. You took away "findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);"??

Comment: No, I didn't mean `meanings` to be `popularity`.  I took away the call to `findingStatistics` because you call it in `main`.

Comment: With that, it's only printing the popularity information and not the meanings

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't understand what was in all the different files.  I have changed my answer so that the call to `changingGraph` is using the contents of `meaningsFile`, not `nameFile` or `nameFile2`.  It would be really good if you showed in the question, what was in the various files; so that people like me don't have to guess.

Comment: So what's the other line where you've defined it?

Comment: Well, that message is telling you that you declared it twice.  You need to remove one of the declarations.

Comment: OK, that seems to me like a separate question.